# Need help in understanding delete statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw a delete statement written in below format and I need help in understanding it.

```
create table t1 (id int);
create table t2 (id int);

insert into t1 values(1);
insert into t1 values(2);
insert into t2 values(1);

delete t1
from t2
where t1.id = t2.id;
```

I tried above in online SQL Server database but script is failing. I am not sure how similar script is running in production environment.

Comment: The script in your question will work if you specify a valid data type in the `CREATE TABLE` statements

Comment: The number in both the tables should be int instead of the number.

Comment: Raj please check this it is working https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8387a8df9678ad0d0202a008c2b9e574

Comment: "I tried above in online SQL Server database but script is failing." - please submit bugs WITH ERROR REPORT. Voting to close until then due to extremely low quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DELETE](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement has the following syntax:

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]  
DELETE   
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ]   
    [ FROM ]   
    { { table_alias  
      | <object>   
      | rowset_function_limited   
      [ WITH ( table_hint_limited [ ...n ] ) ] }   
      | @table_variable  
    }  
    [ <OUTPUT Clause> ]  
    [ FROM table_source [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ WHERE { <search_condition>   
            | { [ CURRENT OF   
                   { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name }   
                       | cursor_variable_name   
                   }   
                ]  
              }  
            }   
    ]   
    [ OPTION ( <Query Hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]   
[; ]
```

When pinpointing the parts from your example, you get:

```
DELETE   
    { 
        <object>   
    }  
    [ FROM table_source [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ WHERE { <search_condition>    
            }   
    ]
```

Being `<object>` the following:

```
<object> ::=  
{   
    [ server_name.database_name.schema_name.   
      | database_name. [ schema_name ] .   
      | schema_name.  
    ]  
    table_or_view_name   
}
```

So what your `DELETE` statement is doing is joining table `t1` with `t2` via a condition on the `WHERE` clause, and then deleting all matching records from table `t1`.

---

Regular SQL syntax requires is to filter your rows from a `WHERE` clause:

```
DELETE FROM <table>
WHERE <condition>
```

Transact-SQL has a few extensions to this base format. First, the `FROM` is optional, so you can write:

```
DELETE <table>
WHERE <condition>
```

and second, **you can filter rows from your deleting table through joining against other table sources** (which is pretty common), so they give you the option to move some of your `WHERE` conditions to an optional, new `FROM <table_source>` clause.

```
DELETE <table>
FROM <table_source>
WHERE <condition>
```

The `FROM` from the first point is still optional, you can also write:

```
DELETE FROM <table>
FROM <table_source>
WHERE <condition>
```

And you can put your joining conditions on either a `JOIN`:

```
DELETE a
FROM t1 as a INNER JOIN t2 as b on a.id = b.id
```

or the `WHERE`:

```
DELETE t1
FROM t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

But I suggest using the former, since it's easier to read for bigger queries.

Comment: Its not about how to write, I am oracle sql developer. For one bug related to sql server code, I was analyzing the stored procedure and there I saw a delete statement in this format. It works fine but I am curious to know as how it works in sql server.

Comment: It can be confusing since you can reference either a table or an alias of a table to delete before the `FROM`. If it's a table then you can use it's columns to join or filter in the `WHERE` (without repeating it after the `FROM`), if it's an alias then you have to mention the proper table with the alias in the `FROM`.

Comment: And since the addition of CTEs, it's usually better to just write a CTE subquery and target that in your DELETE or UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write join as shown below to delete the record which is in both tables.

You can learn in more detail about here to [Delete and Update Rows Using Inner Join in SQL Server](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56823/delete-update-rows-using-inner-join-sql-server/).

```
delete t1
from Firsttable t1
inner join Secondtable t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where <put your condition here>
```

[**Live Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8123967c00c33cb5f5b9af6b94c894f)

Comment: Thanks, even I was thinking in same line but what I have written in question is a production code. Not sure how it is working in sql server.

Comment: @Raj I have taken t1 and t2 as table alias you can also give the actual name. Check the demo.

Comment: Its not about how to write, I am oracle sql developer. For one bug related to sql server code, I was analyzing the stored procedure and there I saw a delete statement in this format. It works fine but I am curious to know as how it works in sql server.

Comment: @Raj There may be different ways like inner join delete, using exists or using where as you have written. I think you should go to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type **int** instead of **number** as number is invalid in SQL Server:

```
    create table t1(id int);
    create table t2(id int);
```

[image]